# Jruby 1.7.4 installation with rvm is failing for Mac 10.12

Tags: macos, ant, rvm, jruby

I am setting up environment for rails project which support 1.7.4. I am using rvm and hence proceeded with installing Jruby 1.7.4 on Mac 10.12.6 (Macbook Air) with the help of rvm itself.

rvm install 1.7.4

Below is what my output looks like

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/jruby-1.7.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Requirements installation successful.
HEAD is now at 2390d3b024 Bump for 1.7.4
Previous HEAD position was 2390d3b024... Bump for 1.7.4
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
From https://github.com/jruby/jruby
 * branch                  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
git checkout 1.7.4
Copying from repo to src path...
jruby-1.7.4 - #ant jar.......
Error running '__rvm_ant jar',
please read /Users/solid/.rvm/log/1506220984_jruby-1.7.4/ant.jar.log
```

If I try to install any other version of ruby such as 2.4.1 or 2.0.0, it works.
Below are the contents of the ant.jar.log file

```
[2017-09-24 08:13:04] __rvm_ant
__rvm_ant () 
{ 
    \ant "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/solid/.rvm/bin
command(2): __rvm_ant jar
++ ant jar
Buildfile: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build.xml

init:

prepare-bin-jruby:

jar:

init:

create-dirs:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/test
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/test-results
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/test-results/html
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/docs/api

copy-resources:
     [copy] Copying 45 files to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby

copy-bc-resources:
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared

update-constants:
     [echo] Updating Constants.java
     [echo] ...using git revision = 2390d3b024, tzdata = 2012j
     [copy] Warning: Could not find file /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/src_gen/org/jruby/runtime/Constants.java to copy.
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/src_gen/org/jruby/runtime

_uc_internal_:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/src_gen/org/jruby/runtime
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 4 warnings

prepare:

compile-annotation-binder:
    [javac] Compiling 18 source files to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] Note: /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/src/org/jruby/util/CodegenUtils.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 4 warnings

compile-jruby:
    [javac] Compiling 1395 source files to /Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build/classes/jruby
    [javac] -Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
    [javac] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    [javac] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

BUILD FAILED
/Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build.xml:636: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/solid/.rvm/src/jruby-1.7.4/build.xml:289: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds
++ return 1
```

Please let me know if you need any other info on setup/environment!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That version is not available for OSX. https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.12/x86_64/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735805/what-does-no-binary-rubies-available-mean

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using? I suspect it is not compatible with JRuby 1.7.4. Notice the errors above like "bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6".